# OpenGL: What else could be the bottleneck here?

Tags: performance, opengl, profiling, gpu

I optimized our stereo application to become GPU bound by batching pretty much all the geometry (about 1600 draw calls) into a single draw call (per eye). Now that we are GPU bound I want to figure out how to improve GPU performance of this single render call, however, it's difficult to pinpoint the bottleneck.

In all screenshots, the render calls in question are those with ID 91 and 154!

Rendering the Scene as is and profiling a frame with Nvidia's NSIGHT (I am rendering on a NVidia Geforce GTX 980), I get the following frame timing (note: 1 & 3 are the ones of interest):
[image]
These render calls take about 5ms each.

The frame profiler shows the following bottleneck percentage:
[image]
with corresponding shader type utilisation:
[image]

This seems to hint at the fragment shader being the bottleneck of the render call. While the fragment shader we use is fairly complex, I would have expected to be geometry limited (the draw call renders an indexed triangle list with ~600'000 triangles).

Seeing these results, **I replaced the pixel shader with one that simply outputs the interpolated vertex normal**. With the simple fragment shader, the frame profiler reports no significant bottleneck for the rendercall, **however, it still takes the same time.**
(the following screenshots are profiled with the simplified fragment shader being used to render):
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, with the fragment shader replaced by a much simpler version, the shader stage does not show up anymore as a bottleneck and yet the render call still takes the same amount of time on the GPU. **What else could be the bottle neck of the render call?**

To give further insight, here are the hardware counters for the profiled frame
with complex fragment shader:
[image]
and with simple fragment shader:
[image]

I also tried to lower the screen resolution (half size in either dimension), which neither did result in a faster render call.

Any ideas how I could further pinpoint why these render calls do not consume less time on the GPU?

Comment: First thing I'd look into is memory layout. You have a pretty huge IBO there and, depending on order of the indices inside, you could be spending a whole lot of time with vertex cache misses. http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~blancher/projects/vertex_caching/vertex_caching_eb.pdf

Comment: An easier thing to do is just avoid IBOs and use a complete triangle specification -- more data and memory use that way, but it's cache-friendly and you can see from the paper's benchmarks that, without sorting the IBO properly for vertex cache efficiency, it's often faster to just not use indices for such complex meshes otherwise.

Comment: Another easier thing to do is just use smaller VBOs/IBOs and use more rendering calls. It's better to be cache-friendly here than to have the minimum number of calls at the cost of it, and so smaller VBOs/IBOs can help if you don't want to bother sorting them for locality. It's not as simple as making one massive IBO/VBO and letting the GPU go fast -- the data needs to be arranged in a way that's cache-friendly for it to go really fast, or else making bigger VBOs/IBOs can hurt more than help.

Comment: are you sure you're only outputing the interpolated normal? there are loads of texture fetches in the simple fragment shader case. Are those coming from the vertex shader?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your input! You are right there was still a texture fetch, removing that does not change something about the draw call duration however. The indices are already cache optimized - also, if better post transform cache utilization could make the draw call faster, wouldn't that mean that the shader stage (in particular vertex shader) should show up as a bottleneck for the render call?

Comment: On the simple case, there are 7x the ps insts vs. vs insts (based on ratios). For ~5x the amount of verts (based on prim count, I don't see exact # of verts). So your PS is non-trivial. Making it trivial and capturing new metrics might help see better. But I'm thinking you're hitting a bottleneck that the metrics don't call out. Things that come to mind are limited. Latency coverage in shaders? possibly too much data in the interpolants - the values you pass from the VS to the PS. I would have thought that would be optimized away in the simple fragment case though.